# Como fazer tela Splash?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo um app para android usando eclipse, neste app, quando inicia ele, eu precisava ter uma tela de apresentação (tela splash), ou seja, uma tela com meu logo, ai esperar uns 4 segundos, e ir pra tela de login. Tem como eu fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, essa "tela de apresentação" se chama Splash Screen (que nem a logo do Eclipse quando vc inicia ele)

Você pode colocar o layout inicial como a splash screen (layout fullscreen) e depois no seu source usar o Sleep ou algo parecido:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342651/how-can-i-delay-a-java-program-for-a-few-seconds

Depois de 'dormir', você pode fazer a próxima linha de código mudar de layout para o layout principal.

Comment: valew vou tentar aqui